# MIPS Assembly: How can I access different size of data on the .data area?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to access a halfword change it's value and then save it. After that do the same for a word.

My understanding is that a halfword uses 2 bytes so when loading the address of the .word I use an offset of 2 in the load instruction.

```
.data
.half 49 
.word 450

.text 

li $gp, 0x10010000

lb $t1, 0($gp)
addi $t1,$0,49
sw $t1, 0($gp)


add $t3,$gp,2
lw $t1, 0($t3)
addi $t1,$0,600
sw $t1, ($t3)
```

However I'm getting this error:

> Error in line 15: Runtime exception at 0x00400018: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010002

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As the error message says, words have to be aligned on word boundaries. It's possible that your assembler automatically aligned the word data for you so that it's actually located at  0x10010004. If not, you'll have to do so yourself with `.align 2` or whatever directive your assembler uses. And of course, it should be `add $t3,$gp,4`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I think my problem was in thinking that the directive .half or .word aligned the values. What I have to do then is something like:  `.word .align 4 450 ?`

Comment: _"I think my problem was in thinking that the directive .half or .word aligned the values."_ As I said, they might. But you're still trying to read from the non-word-aligned address 0x10010002 because you do `add $t3,$gp,2`.

Comment: I think I´m not getting something. Isn´t the instruction `add $t3,$gp,2` going to add 2 bytes? And since the first data is aligned in a halfword (ie 2 bytes). The second data (the word ) would be 2 bytes away from the original address 0x10010000? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: The halfword is at 0x10010000, which is both halfword- and word-aligned. You then add 2 to that address - which gives you 0x10010002 - and attempt to read a word from that address. 0x10010002 is not word-aligned, so you get an exception.

Comment: Oh that clears a lot thank you! I there any way I can make the halfword at 0x10010000 both halword and word aligned so I can use the instruction `add $t3,$gp,2` to get the correct adress of the word?

Comment: @PabloEstrada: address 0x10010000 is both halfword and word aligned. Address 0x10010002 is only halfword aligned. Addresses are word aligned if their last nibble is either 0, 4, 8, or C.